# Invalid format issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jsFiddle here, please open in Internet Explorer and in one other major browser:

http://jsfiddle.net/7sARw/47/

Now in the jsFiddle, just click on the "Add Question" button and it will append a row underneath. In the row it shows 2 rows of letter buttons (each row containing 7 letter buttons) and two buttons, one known as "Select All Answers" and other known as "Remove All Answers".

Now in the major browser, the buttons are centered in the table which is fine. But in Internet Explorer it is not centered , it is still aligned to the left.  Now the reason I believe it is doing this is because of the way the HTML is being formatted when appending the row: which seems to be going like this:

```
<tr><td><div><tr><td></td></tr></div></td></tr>
```

My question is that how can **I change the format of the HTML** so that it is valid but also be able to center everything in the appended rows in Internet Explorer?

Below is the CSS and jQuery/HTML of the code:

```
.answer { 
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    padding-top:5%;
    padding-bottom:5%;
     }

.answerBtnsRow{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: #666666 1px solid;
    color: black;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:85%;    
    }    


    .allBtnsRow{
        text-align:center;
        cursor:pointer;
        font-size:85%;  
    }

    .allRemoveBtnsRow{
        text-align:center;
        cursor:pointer;
        font-size:85%;  
    }
```

Below is Jquery/HTML code:

```
function insertQuestion(form) {

    var context = $('#optionAndAnswer');
    var currenttotal = context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length;

    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody');
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'>");
    var $td = $("<td class='extratd'>");
    var $answer = $("<div class='answer'>3. Answer:<br/></div>");
    var $questionType = '';

    gQuestionIndex++;



    var $this, i = 0,
        $row, $cell;
    $('#optionAndAnswer .answers').each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        if (i % 7 == 0) {
            $row = $("<tr/>").appendTo($answer);
            $cell = $("<td/>").appendTo($row);
        }
        var $newBtn = $(("<input class='answerBtnsRow answers' type='button' style='display:%s;' onclick='btnclick(this, " + gQuestionIndex + ");' />").replace('%s', $this.is(':visible') ? 'inline-block' : 'none')).attr('name', "value[" + gQuestionIndex + "][]").attr('value', $this.val()).attr('class', $this.attr('class')).attr('id', $this.attr('id') + 'Row');
        $newBtn.appendTo($cell);

        i++;
    });    var $this = $(this);
    var $BtnsClass = '';

    $row = $("<tr/>").appendTo($answer);
    $cell = $("<td/>").appendTo($row);

    if ($questionType == 'True or False' || $questionType == 'Yes or No') {
        $BtnsClass = $("<input class='allBtnsRow btnsAll' type='button' style='display: none;' value='Select All Answers' onClick='selectAll(this);' /><input class='allRemoveBtnsRow btnsRemove' type='button' style='display: none;' value='Remove All Answers' onClick='removeAll(this);' />");
    } else {
        $BtnsClass = $("<input class='allBtnsRow btnsAll' type='button' value='Select All Answers' onClick='selectAll(this);' /><br/><input class='allRemoveBtnsRow btnsRemove' type='button' value='Remove All Answers' onClick='removeAll(this);' />");
    }
    $BtnsClass.appendTo($cell);





    $tr.append($td);
    $td.append($answer);
    $tbody.append($tr);

    count++;
    $('#optionAndAnswer .answerBtns').hide();

    updateAnswer($answer, gQuestionIndex);



}
```

Comment: Why do you append a TR to a DIV? You should not even need the div `$row = $("<tr/>").appendTo($answer);`

Comment: is this an assignment for some course? The same UI keeps showing up over and over with different code approaches

Comment: @mplungjan It is because in that appended row, it will contain multiple features, `.options`, `.noanswer` and `.answers`. This one is just showing `.answers` in the appended row. But I want it to show `.options` at top of row, then `.noanswers` below that, then the `.answer` section below that.

Comment: @charlietfl It is web developing tasks, not assignments but just extra tasks for extra learning.

Comment: Does not matter what it will contain. That line is what breaks your page. It is not producing valid hmtl

Comment: would have a lot less problems if you simply created hard code html with several rows in it... validate all the html through W3c, get all your css working and then create the dynamic insertion html script based on the structure you know works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $td = $("<td class='extratd'>");
var $answer = $("<div class='answer'>3. Answer:<br/></div>");
```

should likely be

```
var $td = $("<td class='extratd' />3. Answer:<br/></td>");
var $answer = $("<table class='answer'><tbody></tbody></table>");
```

or

```
$cell = $("<td>3. Answer<br/></td>").appendTo($row);
```

Comment: As i want `3. Answers` in `$answer` variable, should it be `var $answer = $("<table class='answer'><tbody><tr><td>3. Answer:</td></tr></tbody></table>");`?

Comment: As long as you do not use a div, then you can put the answer text wherever you want. However then I suggest you change to `$cell = $("<td>3. Answer<br/></td>").appendTo($row);`

Comment: I might just have centre problems in other browsers. Let me just test and see what happens. Maybe some css needs to be modifeld

Comment: Yeah by manipulating fiddle which is here: http://jsfiddle.net/7sARw/52/ I have found out that it does center table contents in IE but not in major browsers. So my question is what is best method to center it, shall I float:center, or deal with margins?

Comment: Its ok, realised that it is text-align center I need to use within the table class

Answer (score 1):

make the `<div class='answer'>` a table.

Comment: Should the div tag just be changed to table tag or does it need to be a little bit like mplugjan answer?

Comment: just changed to table should be fine. you will need to apply a style of text-align:center to the table as well

Comment: i usually avoid tables all together, if you would like an example without tables let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a few general inconsistencies you run into occasionally with Internet Explorer's DOM parsing compared to other browsers.  There are a few things I would recomend trying first, mainly adding width styles to all of the container classes.  Not sure if IE 9 defaults to 100% width on common tags or still reacts like an inline block but that sometimes is an issue.

I would also agree that you shouldn't have a row inside a div inside a row in your table.  You should do as suggested mplungjan and generate a complete table to instead of the div and new tr.